# Ошибка что переменная не обьявлена, но она обьявлена

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

```
    public float firespeed;
    public float tempfirespeed;
    public float reloadspeed;
    public int ammo;
    public float damage;
    public GameObject crosshair;
    public ParticleSystem fireeffect;

    void Start()
    {
        tempfirespeed = firespeed;
    }
```

возникает ошибка
`Assets\shoot.cs(22,9): error CS0103: The name 'tempfirepeed' does not exist in the current context`
хотя переменная уже обьявлена он пишет что не обьявлена

Answer (score 0):

"tempfirepeed" не равно "tempfire**S**peed"

Я это выяснил банально попытавшись сделать поиск по имени, указанному в ошибке

---

Как вы пишите код без IDE и без автодополнения?

Comment: спасибо я оказывается просто не заметил,
код пишу в визуал студио, автозаполнение включить как не знаю